# Remote disk monitoring with WMI without admin rights

Tags: security, monitoring, powershell, wmi

I am setting up a restricted WMI group that should be able to read WMI information from my remote hosts.

I have the group set up as member of the remote DCOM and performance monitor groups. I also have the Execute, Enable and Remote Enable set in the WMI control interface.

The values I get if I run this from a full admin look like the following.

```
PS Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername myhost


DeviceID     : M:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName :
FreeSpace    : 2279043964928
Size         : 3790830256128
VolumeName   : Static Data
```

Run from the same server using the restricted account I'm getting the following:

```
DeviceID     : M:
DriveType    : 3
ProviderName : 
FreeSpace    : 
Size         : 
VolumeName   :
```

My best guess is that there is an additional level of security I need to set but I don't have any idea where.

Suggestions?

*EDIT:*
Looks like this issue only crops up on 2003 hosts and then only on specific disks.

Comment: Deleted my first answer since it didn't help.  I'll post a better answer if I think of one.

Comment: Have you checked the ACL on the root of the drive?

Comment: @LuckyLuke - nope.. Good idea though.

Comment: Glad I could help, will do that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ACL on the root of the drive, it's often overlooked and can cause issues like this. I have seen this a few times with our monitoring software - though we're not using WMI to query the drive stats.